# CDI when injectionpoint.getBean() can be null

Tags: dependency-injection, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm playing with CDI producers and spotted in doc that

```
InjectionPoint.getBean()
```

can return null if the injection point does not belong to a bean.
What does it effectively mean? How can injection point not belong to a bean? Is it possible to inject something into something other what is not CDI bean?

I'd like to get class name of class containing this injection point and now I don't know if I can rely on `getBean()` method if it can return null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are VERY good (AFAIK) you'd only see a null if you manually created an InjectionPoint through an extension.

Comment: Is there any reason to do that? I mean to create InjectionPoint by hand? I can't make up any scenario at the moment

Comment: Integration with some other frameworks, bytecode manipulation, perhaps if you don't know the exact class at boot time (maybe there are some proxies in place or something similar). The usages aren't very large that's for sure.

Comment: One more scenario when getBean() returns null: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34643780/5300071