# injectionPoint.getBean() returns null if bean is an EJB bean in Java EE 7 (CDI 1.1)

Tags: cdi, ejb-3.1, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I want to get bean from producer method in order to read its properties. In some scenarios the bean is a `EJB Singleton` bean.

I've simplified my code to focus on the problem.

My simple qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface InjectMe {}
```

Simple producer:

```
@Dependent
public class SimpleProducer {

    @Produces
    @InjectMe
    public String getInjectMe(InjectionPoint ip) {
        // ip.getBean() returns null for some reason   
        return "ip=" + ip + ", bean=" + ip.getBean();
    }
}
```

EJB (Singleton):

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class SimpleSingleton {

    @Inject
    @InjectMe
    private String injectMe;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(injectMe);
   }
```

}

Console output:

> Info: ip=[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @InjectMe private com.test.ejb.SimpleSingleton.injectMe, `bean=null`

When I change `Singleton` bean to `CDI` bean everything works fine (`ip.getBean()` returns not null). It also worked in `Java EE 6` even with `Singleton` bean but it does not in `Java EE 7`. I am using Glassfish 4 application server.

Is this behavior specified somewhere?

Comment: Sounds like a glassfish bug.

Comment: @JohnAment: Don't think so, the same behaviour for WildFly.
Can't answer the question yet, but possible reasons may be: 1) change of bean discovery module behaviour (default: `annotated`); 2) injecting a (non-contextual) class String; 3) having no declared scope other than `Dependent`

Comment: If you call `ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass()`, you'll get for both cases the FQCN, this is also used as an example in the InjectionPoint API doc and I have seen it in a Deltaspike example as a followup call after `bean` is `null`.

Comment: @Alexander Rühl: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately nothing of the above works: I've changed discovery mode to "all", changed scope of producer bean, producer method and singleton bean. Changed `@Singleton` to `@Stateless`, changed `String` type to my own. I even can't use `ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass()` because in my scenario I inject produced value into an abstract class and need access to the base class from producer method (I need its annotation) but `ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass()` returns abstract class. You've written you tried it with WildFly. Does it work the same way?

Comment: @A.Panzer: Yes, tried the same things, but was always null, don't know why. And strange, it behaves different in CDI 1.0. Probably the only thing you can do to find that out is to link the source jars of CDI implementation to your project and step to the point where `getBean()`gets called.

Comment: You can use application server specific API implementations. For glassfish 4 you may try something like this: ((SessionBeanInjectionPoint.NonContextualSessionBeanInjectionPoint) ip).delegate().getBean()

Comment: Using AS specific implementations is worst solution. I would rather say no solution at all.

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass()
```

works for me in WildFly 10.1.0 and I also quickly tested it in Payara Server  4.1.1.162 #badassfish (build 116). I also did a test on brand new Payara Server  4.1.1.164 #badassfish (build 28). However,I had to change the scope of the producer bean to @ApplicationScoped. Default scope did not work. In my case, it even makes sense :)

The

```
injectionPoint.getBean().getBeanClass()
```

method worked for me in the old Payara, but not in the new WildFly 10.1.0.Final and new Payara Server  4.1.1.164 #badassfish (build 28).

If you have a look at Payara, the current new version 164 contains Weld 2.4.0.Final and WildFly 10.1.0Final uses version 2.3.5.Final. In both versions, the classical code does not work !

The conclusion is, on older CDI implementations (Weld), it works. In some newer Weld (introduced in Payara 161), the behavior changed. I do not know if this is intentional or not.

However, the **solution is to use**

```
injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass()
```

and annotate the producer bean with

```
@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
```

annotation.

Comment: Tested on weblogic 12.2.1 (CDI 1.1) and I also have the same problem. While it was working fine on weblogic 12.1.3 (CDI 1.0). As you said, I solved the problem using `injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass()`